# Output when using pre decrement in for loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, decrement

As you can see this the code in C, here I have used in `for` loop `--i` for decrement but I am not getting the expected output. Please explain

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n, i = 1;
    printf("Enter the number ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (i <= n) {
        printf("%d ", i++);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = n; i >= 1; --i) {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output for n=6.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

but I am expecting it to be like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't be printing 6 twice?

Comment: In the second loop you decrement *after* printing. Since `i` is 6 when the loop starts, the first number you print in the second loop is 6.

Comment: The decrement happens after the loop has iterated.

Comment: @ABHINAV Bhushan In the for loop     for(i=n;i>=1;--i)
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
    } i initially is set to n that is to 6 that is outputted.

Comment: Your expectation would be correct if you had the decrement in the `printf()` call, like the increment in the first loop.

Comment: @ABHINAV Bhushan Change the compiler or the computer!:)

Comment: If you expect the first loop value to be 5 because you are using pre decrement operator on "--i", take a look at @the busybee s answer. The pre decrement operator yields its result after its operation, but its execution in your code is just placed at the bottom of the loop and the result is never evaluated. So using --i or i--, doesn't result in any difference with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `for` loop can be replaced with a `while` loop. The initializing statement (1st part of `for`) comes first, then the conditional loop (condition: 2nd part of `for`), and the loop statement (3rd part of `for`) is executed right before the loop repeats.

Your loop:

```c
    for (i = n; i >= 1; --i)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
```

is equivalent to:

```c
    i = n;
    while (i>=1)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
        --i;
    }
```

So the output is correct, and your expectation is wrong.

---

But *why* has the `for` loop the loop statement in its parentheses, so that some beginners assume it executes *before* the loop body?

This shows the coherence between all the loop's parts. Consider a loop body of multiple lines. The trailing loop statement (for example, increment the index) would be far away from the leading initialization statement and the condition. And this is more work for your brain to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

In this for loop

```
for(i=n;i>=1;--i)
{
    printf("%d ",i);
}
```

the variable `i` is initiallially set to `n`. As its value is not less than `1` then the value of `n` is outputted in the first iteration of the loop. After that before the second iteration of the loop the variable `i` is decremented.

The conditon of the loop evaluates to logical true when `i` is in the range `[n, 1]` where `n` is not less than `1`.

Actually these two loops

```
for(i=n;i>=1;--i)
{
    printf("%d ",i);
}
```

and

```
for(i=n;i>=1; i--)
{
    printf("%d ",i);
}
```

are equivalent. It is unimportant whether you will use the pre-decrement operator `--i` or post-decrement operator `i--` in the third expression of the for loop. In any case the value of the variable `i` will be the same after evaluting any of these expressions.

To get the expected result rewrite the for loop for example the following way

```
for (i = n; i > 1; )
{
    printf( "%d ", --i );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: you don't need the "stdlib.h" - remove this line.

Second: always check your code. Debug it with pen and paper if necessary. It may look ridiculous to you, but is one sure way you'll "walk" through your logic, step by step and will check what results is your code producing.

You can solve your problems several ways, but the first solution which came to my mind is to asign n-1 to i, in the begining of the for-loop:

```
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; --i)
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
```

Output:

```
    Enter the number 6
    1 2 3 4 5 6 
    5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: "First: you don't need the "stdlib.h" - remove this line." is noise.  Not needed in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with explanation on why the initial code didn't meet expectations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i=1;
    printf("Enter the number ");
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    while (i<=n)
    {
        printf("%d ",i++);
    }
    printf("\n%d \n", i); /* Updated: note that it prints '7' when input is '6'.  
    ** You/your code apparently expected i to be 6 ... but it's not the case*/

    /* This will do as expected */
    i = n;  /* Added. Assign i to n. */
    while(--i) /* Updated */
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
/*-------------------    
Output:
Enter the number 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
7
5 4 3 2 1 
*-------------------*/
```